# npm package-lock.json optimize by detecting versions that can be merged

Tags: npm, npm-install, package-lock.json

Sometimes, the npm package-lock.json can accumulate pinned dependencies that can be merged together.

For example:

1. Install `A@1`
2. Install `B@1` requires `A@^2` -> pin to `A@2.1`
3. Install `A@latest` -> `A@2.3`

Now, I have two `A` versions:

- `A@2.3`
- `B@1` -> `A@2.1` (which can be updated to A@2.3 and re-use the top-level one instead)

I'd like a command that can detect this merge opportunities to get an optimized dependency tree.

Is there such a thing?